# Is there any methods in Angular to walk scope tree?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any methods in Angular to walk scope tree?

Now I use this method:

```
app.directive('node', function() {
    return {
        link:function(scope) {
            scope.$on('walk', function(event, fn) {
                fn(scope);   
            });
        },
        scope: true
    }; 
});
```

somewhere in code in order to walk I emit event

```
app.controller('Catalog', function($scope) {
    var nodes = [];
    $scope.$broadcast('walk', function(scope) {
       nodes.push(scope);
    });
});
```

for example, for page layout:

```
<div ng-controller="Catalog"> 
    <div node="A"> 
        <div node="A1"> 
        </div>
        <div node="A2"> 
           <div node="A21"> 
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div node="B"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

in `var nodes = []` it will be `A, A1, A2, A21, B`

But this implementation depend on the internal implementation of tree walker in Angular (DFS or WDS), I know that Angular JS use DFS to broadcast event and in loop digest$, but what will be in the future I don't now.

you can try it 
http://jsfiddle.net/olegdunkan/E7ZBq/

Comment: Using $broadcast is performance greedy but that's a good question!

Comment: $broadcast is good enough and isn't greedy to walk if there are not many listeners in scopes but for other cases I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a tree using angularjs, you have to use nesting template.
Here is a component for that:
https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree